# Twitter API - Call 'Latest Tweet'

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

Up until today I was using the following code to display a client's 'Latest Tweet' on their website:

```
<?php
        // Your twitter username.
        $username = "CLIENTTWITTER";

        // Prefix - some text you want displayed before your latest tweet.
        // (HTML is OK, but be sure to escape quotes with backslashes: for example href=\"link.html\")
        $prefix = "";

        // Suffix - some text you want display after your latest tweet. (Same rules as the prefix.)
        $suffix = "";

        $feed = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from:" . $username . "&rpp=1";

        function parse_feed($feed) {
            $stepOne = explode("<content type=\"html\">", $feed);
            $stepTwo = explode("</content>", $stepOne[1]);
            $tweet = $stepTwo[0];
            $tweet = str_replace("&lt;", "<", $tweet);
            $tweet = str_replace("&gt;", ">", $tweet);
            return $tweet;
        }

        $twitterFeed = file_get_contents($feed);
        echo stripslashes($prefix) . parse_feed($twitterFeed) . stripslashes($suffix);
    ?>
```

Today however, it has stopped working. I'm assuming, maybe not correctly, that this is due to the changes with Twitter's API and the fact that they've pulled the plug on v1.0.

Does anyone know of a good replacement to the above code that will work with the current API? Don't want to have to add any additional code if possible. Tried a few but with no success. The Twitter Dev pages confuse me so much.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Use Andrew Biggart php API which is available at https://github.com/andrewbiggart/latest-tweets-php-o-auth/ and makes use of OAuth to authenticate.

The reason why they broke v1.0 is mistery however and even why you need OAuth for a publicly available wall feed.